# INSERT row in table a for every row in table b

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table, A, with only one column (Id). To insert a single row in this table I would use

```
INSERT INTO A default values
```

But now I need to insert a row in table A for every row in another table (B).
To solve similar cases like this in the past I would normally use something like:

```
INSERT INTO XYZ (FkId, Value) 
SELECT Id, EmailAddress FROM ABC
```

But in this scenario, row A only have one column (Id) unfortunately just omitting the values doesn't seem to work

```
INSERT INTO A SELECT Id FROM B
```

edit: by "empty row" I mean a row with only the id automatically set (this: INSERT INTO A default values )

edit 2: Simplified the question to avoid confusion

Comment: Do you mean INSERT INTO a SELECT NULL,NULL FROM b?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "empty" row. A column can be defined as nullable, and NULL is its *default* value in that case, or a column can be defined with an explicit default value. Columns you don't specify in the insert get the default value when a row is inserted.

Comment: _"by "empty row" I mean a row with only the id automatically set (this: INSERT INTO A default values )"_ <-- This explanation doesn't really help because you haven't told us anything about the other columns in the table. Please post your **full** `CREATE TABLE` statement (open SSMS > Tables > Right-click > Script table as > CREATE to > New query window) so we can see for ourselves if an "empty" row is even possible or not.

Comment: Ok there is one thing called "Cascade Update".Provide atleast table structure for both.is Table A has only one column ?

Comment: Table A id should contain what  if 5 is inserted in Table B ?Give one example

Comment: You can use `MERGE` like this `MERGE A USING B ON 1=0 WHEN NOT MATCHED THE INSERT DEFAULT VALUES;`